# Gradle is showing warning messages

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gradle, build.gradle

This is my `gradle` file, I am using same play-service version for all libraries, but its giving warning message on it, and it also crash 1 of the activity on run-time only in lollipop devices, with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error message.

This may be due to the Gradle warning message.

Kindly guide me how to resolve this error message.

```
     compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
        defaultConfig {

            applicationId 'com.myapp.app'
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 103
            versionName "1.2.1"
            multiDexEnabled true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        } 

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.0.1'

}
```

[image]

Comment: you can check if third party libs also use the same versions.

Comment: @Raghunandan How to check that? There are few `aar `files as well in the project .

Comment: on mac `./gradlew app:dependencies` run this command from terminal on windows its `gradlew.bat app:dependencies`. You should get a dependency tree to figure out if third party libs also use the same version. You can have all libs use the same version by defining them in your root build.gradle file and referring them in all your libs

Comment: @Raghunandan different versions of multiple dependencies are using in my project, I can't find all of them in my gradle file, How to find and remove them? or force gradle to use the latest or defined version

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444016/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-set-the-same-version-for-two-dependencies