# how to force the version of dependence in sub gradle project

Tags: android, gradle

I use gradle to import a module which has a version 0.4 of the auto-common created by google.
In my parent module,there is somewhere depend a version 0.6 of that.

In this case,the version of sub module auto take 0.6,and my module works not well.

I wonder know how can i force the version in my sub module but not change the version in other module.

I think I have try [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444016/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-set-the-same-version-for-two-dependencies) but it is not my wanted.it will force to change all the version in the project.

The dependence look like this:

```
+--- project :dagger-complier  
|    +--- com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2 (*)  
|    +--- com.google.android:support-v4:r7  
|    +--- com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2 (*)  
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.6.0 -> 1.8.0  
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1  
|    +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.4 -> 0.6 (*)<-----here is where went wrong
|    \--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0 (*)  
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.3.0    
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.3.0  
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 26.0.1  
|    +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6 (*)  
|    +--- com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2 (*)  
|    \--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
```

Thank for your watching and sorry for my poor english

Comment: in a result ,i change the package name of com.google.auto:auto-common,and package it whit my dagger-complier............and solve this problem..........maybe it has a other way to solve my problem.......