# Error - Program type already present: android.support.compat.R$color

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

When i build the apk of the project than i face this problem at the time of gradle. How to fix this issue
Program type already present: android.support.compat.R$color

````
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enigneerbabu.demos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0' // added for glide
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' // added for volley api
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' //added for gson
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' // Added for Google Sign In
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' // Added for tablayout
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837344/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-app-backstackrecord) you might have a duplication of libraries.

Also try adding this to your `build.gradle`

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`