# Facing issue with shared prefences compat file while compile and run application

Tags: android, gradle, sharedpreferences

I am facing issue with sharedprefences file while trying to compile the project. I tried all ways to fix. But no success.

Please check error as below for reference.

```
Type android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat$Helper is referenced as an interface from `android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat$EditorHelperApi9Impl`.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Type android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat$Helper is referenced as an interface from `android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat$EditorHelperApi9Impl`., sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

If anyone have idea. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding v4 reference to app gradle file implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'

Comment: Thanks for resposne @Giddy Naya, But it producing another error. Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver

Comment: Another library in your app gradle is also referencing the v4 support library but a different version other than 27.+ which causes the new conflict error.  You can follow the answer on this post to force your own specified version of v4. [See post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434505/8043806) if that would help. And also make sure you're using the latest support libraries for your build.

Comment: Thanks @GiddyNaya  The issue was related to firebase library.