# Gradle find wrong maven repository url in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

this is my `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{url 'http://example.com/repository/maven-public/'}
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.example', name: 'example-commlib', version: '1.0'
}
```

and the link `http://example.com/repository/maven-public/` is build from Nexus Repository Manager which can accessable.

and when I click `Refresh Gradle Project` in eclipse.
I can see the link is point to

`https://repo.maven.apache.org/..../example-commlib-1.0.pom`

I think the right url is

`http://example.com/repository/maven-public/.../example-commlib-1.0.pom`

I've check the gradle setting and maven setting in eclipse. It seems fine.

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other dependencies on this project? It is possible that the "pom.xml" file of one of the packages  you are pulling references example-commlib as a dependency and has the  Apache Maven URL hardcoded, and resolves the URL beforehand. You can use `gradle dependencies` to show the dependency tree and find which version is affected. The answers in this post have suggestions on how to force a specific dependency as well: [How can I force Gradle to set the same version for two dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444016/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-set-the-same-version-for-two-dependencies)

Comment: yes, I have other dependencies  on this projects. but it seems no any dependencies relate to example-commlib. and so weird is that if I run the command `gradlew bootJar`, there is totally normal without any errors. The errors just come in the eclipse IDE.

Comment: I see. I did not realize the issue is only in IDE build. Doing some research I see  
The mavenCentral() alias means that dependencies are fetched from the central Maven 2 repository. his is probably where your unexpected link is coming from. Try flipping the order of mavenCentral() and maven{url 'http://example.com/repository/maven-public/'}, Gradle will look for dependencies in the repository order you specify.

Comment: yeah. I've tried flip it. but it stuck in the `synchronize gradle project`. looks like it cant connect to `maven{url 'example.com/repository/maven-public'}`

Comment: Ok . I'd suggest a test where maven{url 'example.com/repository/maven-public'} is your only repository, and then trying to debug the connection issue locally. Perhaps the URL is not accessible locally, and you can source the same .pom from a different URL.