# Duplicate class error in Android dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing this issue of duplicate class.

- com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.1.4
  In this third party, the classes are inside the package
  In other third parties this dependency is used `"com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1)"`

How do i exclude the package from the 1st third party?

```
api ('com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.1.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
```

I have tried the above code snippet but it doesnt work

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.a.a found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.1-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.1.4-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.1.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.a.b found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.1-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.1.4-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.1.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.a.c found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.1-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.1.4-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.1.4)
```

Comment: Have you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28444896/4017501